# Multiple axios get request not returning the data properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have created a react hook to work on with multiple get request using `axios`

```
const useAxiosGetMultiple = (urls,{preventCall = false} = {}) => {
    
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(()=>{
        const temp = {}
        Object.keys(urls).forEach(key => temp[key] = [])
        return temp
    })

    const [reloadToken, setReloadToken] = useState(false)

    const urlObj = useRef({...urls})
    const unmountedOnReload = useRef(false)
    
    useEffect(() => {

        if(preventCall === true){
            return null
        }
        
        let unmounted = false;

        const source = axios.CancelToken.source();

        setLoading(true)
        
        const requests = []

        Object.values(urlObj.current).forEach(url => {
            requests.push(
                axios.get(url, {
                    cancelToken: source.token,
                })
            );
        });

        const result = {}
        const errors = {}
        
        console.log(requests)

        Promise.allSettled(requests)
        .then(resArray => {
            if(!unmounted){
                console.log('from promise allsettled')
                console.log(resArray)
                console.log(urlObj.current)
                Object.keys(urlObj.current).forEach((key,i) =>{
                    
                    if(resArray[i].status === 'fulfilled'){
                    
                        result[key] = resArray[i].value.data.responseData
                    
                    }
                    if(resArray[i].status === 'rejected'){
                    
                        errors[key] = resArray[i].reason
                        result[key] = []
                    
                    }
                })

                setError(errors)
                setLoading(false)
                setResponse(result)
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {

            if (!unmounted) {

                setError(err);
                setLoading(false);
                setResponse([])
                
                if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
                    console.log(`request cancelled:${err.message}`);
                } else {
                    console.log("another error happened:" + err.message);
                }
            }
        })
        return () => {
            unmounted = true;
            unmountedOnReload.current = true
            source.cancel("Api call cancelled on unmount");
        };

    }, [reloadToken,preventCall]);

    const reFetchAll = () => {

        setReloadToken((token) => !token);
        
    };

    const reload = (urlKey) =>{
        
        unmountedOnReload.current = false
        
        setLoading(true)
        
        axios.get(urls[urlKey])
        .then(res =>{
            if(!unmountedOnReload.current){

                setLoading(false)
                setResponse({...response,[urlKey]: res.data.responseData})
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            if(!unmountedOnReload.current){

                setLoading(false)
                setError({...error, [urlKey]: err})
                setResponse({...response,[urlKey]: []})
            }
        })

    }

    return {response, loading, error, reFetchAll, reload, setLoading};
};
```

I call this hook as follows..

```
const {response,loading,setLoading,reload} = useAxiosGetMultiple({
        stateCodes: StateCode.api,
        countryCodes: CountryCode.api,
        districts: District.api,
    })
```

Rather than getting variable stateCodes containing state codes or countryCodes containing country codes it's returning in wrong order or returning same data in multiple variable. Every time the call happens every time it changes. I also tried axios.all method instead of Promise.all but problem remains same.
Even in chrome's network panel the response data is improper.
What's the possible cause for this error and how to fix it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If your data is incorrect in the Network tab as well, then it's your API that's sending you incorrect data. The wrong order is probably because of the asynchronous `forEach`/`then`/`push` that should be replaced with a `map`/`Promise.allSettled`/`then`.

Comment: @FZs the api sending data is always correct when its called alone. And in my case the problem is not only about data order,  the data is same in more than one responses